# ShowHide plugin: Fade in instead of toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

I'm using the ShowHide Plugin and I'm trying to get it to fade in instead of toggle/slide into view.  Here is what I have:

showHide.js

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

    //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Show',
            hideText: 'Hide'

        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () {
// optionally add the class .toggleDiv to each div you want to automatically close
                      $('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);
             // this var stores which button you've clicked
             var toggleClick = $(this);
             // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
             var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');
             // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
             $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function() {
             // this only fires once the animation is completed
             if(options.changeText==1){
             $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
             }
              });

          return false;

        });

    };
})(jQuery);


$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.show_hide').showHide({
        speed: 1000,  // speed you want the toggle to happen
        easing: '',  // the animation effect you want. Remove this line if you dont want an effect and if you haven't included jQuery UI
        changeText: 1, // if you dont want the button text to change, set this to 0
        showText: 'View',// the button text to show when a div is closed
        hideText: 'Close' // the button text to show when a div is open

    });

});
```

HTML

```
<a class="show_hide" href="#" rel="#slidingDiv">View</a></pre>
<div id="slidingDiv" class="toggleDiv" style="display: none;">Fill this space with really interesting content.</div>
<pre>
 <a class="show_hide" href="#" rel="#slidingDiv_2">View</a></pre>
<div id="slidingDiv_2" class="toggleDiv" style="display: none;">Fill this space with really interesting content.</div>
<pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the line `$('.toggleDiv').slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);`, here you should not slideup the target div - use `$('.toggleDiv').not(toggleDiv).slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);`

Try

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.showHide = function (options) {

        //default vars for the plugin
        var defaults = {
            speed: 1000,
            easing: '',
            changeText: 0,
            showText: 'Show',
            hideText: 'Hide'

        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).click(function () {
            // this var stores which button you've clicked
            var toggleClick = $(this);
            // this reads the rel attribute of the button to determine which div id to toggle
            var toggleDiv = $(this).attr('rel');

            // optionally add the class .toggleDiv to each div you want to automatically close
            $('.toggleDiv').not(toggleDiv).slideUp(options.speed, options.easing);


            // here we toggle show/hide the correct div at the right speed and using which easing effect
            $(toggleDiv).slideToggle(options.speed, options.easing, function () {
                // this only fires once the animation is completed
                if (options.changeText) {
                    $(toggleDiv).is(":visible") ? toggleClick.text(options.hideText) : toggleClick.text(options.showText);
                }
            });

            return false;

        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bDAjA/)